# Beginner Selenium code not understanding the error it is throwing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi i'm rather new to selenium and understand the basics but cant understand why my basic code it just open a web page is throwing the error its throwing. The error its throwing ill be listed at the bottom.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Selenium1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver ();
    String web = "https://www.facebook.com/";

    Driver.get(web);
    System.out.println(Driver.getTitle());

  }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.(DriverService.java:259)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.(ChromeDriverService.java:101)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>     at Selenium1.main(Selenium1.java:10) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
>     ... 5 more